# specifiy UL properties for nested class (sociallinks) but still it is working as a property of parent class (header) how can i solve it?

Tags: php, css, joomla2.5

[image]

[image]

This are the images of firebug view and css code respectively... please help me to solve this problem that how can i make css code also working for nested class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your personal.css file at the header of the document should be placed after the template.css to overcome the css before declared.

Comment: thanks for reply.... i come to know the solution of the problem.. just i make my class as id so it is also working properly... cause i per the rule of css .... it is gives first preference to id compare to class... thanks again... :)